# Date string format to NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a date string format like this :

```
2007-04-28T03:00:33.000Z
```

And i want to convert it to `NSDate` with this method:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:str];
```

But `myDate` is always nil. any idea why?

Comment: Because your format string is wrong.  http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this format

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
NSString *dateString = @"2007-04-28T03:00:33.000Z";
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(dateString.length-3, 1)];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your format to

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ
```